# Jaxb API - Remove JaxbElement

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, eclipselink, jaxb2

I have jaxb Class , in which when attribute is defined as below  then value is loaded in list:

```
    @XmlElementRef(name = "mainElement", namespace = "http://www.xyz.org/spec/524/MODELS", type = JAXBElement.class)
   protected List<JAXBElement<? extends MainElement>> mainElement;
```

when attribute is defined as below  then value is not loaded in list(null contains) :

```
    @XmlElement(name = "mainElement")
 protected List<MainElement> mainElement;
```

Is there a way to remove JAXBElement from java class generated from xsd .

Comment: Try deleting the definition in the XSD and generate JAXB  classes again with xjc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use xjc to generate your classes and if you don't like how they are generating you can change them using an bindings file.  See this stack question and answer for more info. 
[jaxb xjc mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420137/jaxb-xjc-mapping-to-existing-domain-objects)

Also, this blog is really helpful from Blaise Doughan.  http://blog.bdoughan.com/