# importing class into jaxb xsd

Tags: java, jaxb, xsd

Is it possible to use existing Java Classes in XSD to generate other Classes with JAXB?   For a simple example, be able to use COLOR Class in my XSD created class without creating my own Color Class.  We have been generating the Classes and then modifying the generated Java files but this causes issues due to regenerating frequently and then having to modify.

Comment: This seems similar to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420137/jaxb-xjc-mapping-to-existing-domain-objects

Comment: Can you use class from any namespace or is it suppose to be from the current domain?

Comment: @serge Should work with anything. This is how *episodes* work and they're pretty much cross-schema. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756185/what-is-an-episode-file